# Blackpill stm32F411 doesn't enter boot mode anymore

Tags: arduino-ide, stm32

I cannot enter boot mode with my BlackPill F411 board anymore. It's currently running one my sketch successfully uploaded few weeks ago but now, I don't know what's happen.

I've read this [post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/93017/stm32-black-pill-wont-enter-dfu-mode-reliably) which unfortunately doesn't help me.

Blue led doesn't blink, CubeProgrammer 2.14 doesn't detect any DFU mode and Arduino says

```
      -------------------------------------------------------------------
                   STM32CubeProgrammer v2.14.0                  
      -------------------------------------------------------------------



Error: Target device not found
Establishing connection with the device failed
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

I try to upload via USB here is my setting:

[image]

Get_PnpDevice says in PowerShell: "BLACKPILL_F401CC CDC in FS Mode".

Isn't it strange? So do you have any idea please?

I use STM32 MCU based boards 2.6.0, IDE 2.1.1. don't know if it occured after some release.